# In IBM loopback 4, can I use getter and setter for a model property?

Tags: typescript, model, loopbackjs, loopback4

When I generate a model with loopback cli (`lb4 model`) I get a model with some properties. I am specifically trying to make a setter to hash a user entity password.

Initially, I get the following code :

```
@property({
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
})
password: string;
```

I want to know if I can change the code to this :

```
@property({
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
})
private _password: string;

set password(password: string) {
  this._password = Password.hash(password);
}
```

Comment: Hello, did you find the answer for this? Thanks!